# Como cambiar el color de un botón según 0/1 Angular

Tags: angular7

Necesito cambiar el color de un botón según si es 0 o 1
en el HTML :

```
    <tr class="text-white" *ngFor="let item of Velas;let i = index">
            <td class="text-center"> {{i+1}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{item.codigo}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{item.nombre}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" style="list-style:none;"><button type="button" 
      class="btn btn-sm m-2" [ngStyle]="{'font- weight':'bolt','color':'white','font-size':'18px','background':getColorCard(item.encendi)}" >POWER</button>

            </td>
</tr>
```

> y en el componente intente esto pero no me funciona:

```
 getColorCard(encendi) {

  switch (encendi) {
    case 0:
      return this.color = 'green';

    case 1:
      return this.color = 'red';

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass): defines dos clases CSS para los dos estados y eliges la que corresponda en cada momendo:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm m-2" [ngClass]="{ greenClass: encendi, redClass: !encendi}" >POWER</button>
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo me da error , no se si te diste cuenta q estoy trayendo {{item.encendi}} desde una base de datos mysql (campo nombre=encendi y es tinyint(1)). si yo pongo  <td>{{item.encendi}}</td> me pinta 0 y 1 en el html, yo intento q esos 0 y 1 sean botones rojos o verde según corresponda .

Answer (score 0):

¡Lo logré así!

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm m-2 greenClass"
 [class.redClass]="item.encendi =='0'" >POWER</button>
```

Comment: Equivocadisimo!!! soy el autor de la pregunta y estoy aportando como lo solucione no podes decirme q no es la repuesta .

Comment: Deberías dar una explicación clara de lo que hiciste, por si alguien tiene el mismo error saber realmente qué se hizo. Saludos!